# Windows notepad as log

Tags: windows-7, notepad

If I save a notepad as .LOG, it acts as a log file.

My question is when I change an entry **in the middle of an existing file** - it does not append today's date to that.

Is there any way to get that working ?

Comment: It's not automatic, but you can press F5 to manually insert the current time and date.

Comment: love the username! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already know, when you open a text file that begins with `.LOG`, Notepad will scroll to the bottom of the file and insert the time and date.

To manually insert the time and date somewhere else, you can use **Edit** → **Time/Date** or press **F5**.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

Open Notepad and in a new file type .LOG on the first line.

Save it as a .TXT file or .LOG file or whatever filename you want.
The next time you open the file with Notepad, the current date and time will auto-magically be appended to the file.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new trick with Notepad (who would have thought)

Comment: SUPER TRICK!!!!!!!! +1

Comment: My question already covers this. I wanted to know how to add date-time at any location in the file, and **not only at the end**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Notepad only adds current date & time at the end of the file, not anywhere else.

If you're looking for an alternative, use a tool like [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) which substitutes `#date` with current date and `#now` with current time